How to properly extend Shopware standard document templates, like e.g. invoice, in version 6.6?
On extending documents within a theme:
changes to /Resources/views/documents/style_base_portrait.css.twig show up, changes to the base.html.twig next to it don't.
Here is the snippet for testing
{% sw_extends '@Framework/documents/base.html.twig' %}
{% block document_base %}
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body>
        <p>emptymissimo</p>
    </body>
    </html>
{% endblock %}

Something changed w/ 6.6?
What's missing? ‍♂️

Newly created themes' theme.json  configure the views by default in order
"@Plugins",
"@newTheme"```
This order is behaving as expected. The document is overridden.
Whereas for SwagPayPal it is highly recommended to change the order to
```"@Storefront",
"@newTheme",
"@Plugins"```
Many theme vendors use this order.
When doing so, the rendering is all mixed up.
As if not strange enough it is not only for the invoice, which is the only document overriden with the PayPal extension, but all others as well for rendering the standard docs but with the extended styles ...

Worked around by moving all custom documents into SwagPayPal extension and saving as a patch for future updates.
"All" other creating nutty output.
